# Return a list of users

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

I have a DB table with users, i want to return all the users from the table I need a method that returns each user and be able to see that array in Postman in order to compare. Each user contains a list as an atribute besides the other attributes

I´ve created a method that creates the list contained in each user and need to call that method every time i get the user , tried iterating thru a hashmap.

```
private BuyerDataServiceBean armaListaByAll(Map<Integer, Object> mapResults) {

        Map<Integer, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

        BuyerDataServiceBean buyerDataServiceBean = new BuyerDataServiceBean();
        row = (Map<Integer, Object>) mapResults.get("out_cur_buyer_data");
        ArrayList<BuyerDataAdressesBean> adresses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : row.entrySet()) {
            buyerDataServiceBean.setBuyerId(entry.getKey());
            for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(i);

                BuyerDataAdressesBean buyerDataAdressesBean = new BuyerDataAdressesBean();
                if (i == 0) {
                    Map<String, Object> userObj = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(0);
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setLastName(
                            userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME") != null && !userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME").equals("")
                                    ? userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME").toString()
                                    : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setFirstName(
                            userObj.get("NOM_FIRST_NAME") != null && !userObj.get("NOM_FIRST_NAME").equals("")
                                    ? userObj.get("NOM_FIRST_NAME").toString()
                                    : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setPhoneNumber(userObj.get("REF_PHONE") != null && !userObj.get("REF_PHONE").equals("")
                            ? userObj.get("REF_PHONE").toString()
                            : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setIsDeleted(
                            userObj.get("IND_IS_DELETED") != null && !userObj.get("IND_IS_DELETED").equals("")
                                    ? userObj.get("IND_IS_DELETED").toString()
                                    : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setTaxId(userObj.get("REF_TAXID") != null && !userObj.get("REF_TAXID").equals("")
                            ? userObj.get("REF_TAXID").toString()
                            : "");

                    buyerDataServiceBean.setCompany(userObj.get(" REF_COMPANY") != null && !userObj.get("REF_COMPANY").equals("")
                            ? userObj.get("REF_COMPANY").toString()
                            : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setEmailId(userObj.get("REF_EMAIL") != null && !userObj.get("REF_EMAIL").equals("")
                            ? userObj.get("REF_EMAIL").toString()
                            : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setRegistration(
                            userObj.get("STP_REGISTRATION") != null && !userObj.get("STP_REGISTRATION").equals("")
                                    ? userObj.get("STP_REGISTRATION").toString()
                                    : "");
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setId(userObj.get("CVE_BUYER_ID") != null && !userObj.get("CVE_BUYER_ID").equals("")
                            ? Integer.parseInt(userObj.get("CVE_BUYER_ID").toString())
                            : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setBuyerId(userObj.get("NUM_USER_ID") != null && !userObj.get("NUM_USER_ID").equals("")
                            ? Integer.parseInt(userObj.get("NUM_USER_ID").toString())
                            : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);
                    buyerDataServiceBean.setIsActive(
                            userObj.get("IND_IS_ACTIVE") != null && !userObj.get("IND_IS_ACTIVE").equals("")
                                    ? userObj.get("IND_IS_ACTIVE").toString()
                                    : "");

                }
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setNomColony(map.get("NOM_COLONY") != null && !map.get("NOM_COLONY").equals("")
                        ? map.get("NOM_COLONY").toString()
                        : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setNomTown(
                        map.get("NOM_TOWN") != null && !map.get("NOM_TOWN").equals("") ? map.get("NOM_TOWN").toString()
                                : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean
                        .setDesAddrType(map.get("DES_ADDR_TYPE") != null && !map.get("DES_ADDR_TYPE").equals("")
                                ? map.get("DES_ADDR_TYPE").toString()
                                : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setNomStreet(map.get("NOM_STREET") != null && !map.get("NOM_STREET").equals("")
                        ? map.get("NOM_STREET").toString()
                        : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean
                        .setNumPostalCode(map.get("NUM_POSTAL_CODE") != null && !map.get("NUM_POSTAL_CODE").equals("")
                                ? map.get("NUM_POSTAL_CODE").toString()
                                : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setNomMunicipality(
                        map.get("NOM_MUNICIPALITY") != null && !map.get("NOM_MUNICIPALITY").equals("")
                                ? map.get("NOM_MUNICIPALITY").toString()
                                : "");
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setId(map.get("CVE_ADDR_ID") != null && !map.get("CVE_ADDR_ID").equals("")
                        ? Integer.parseInt(map.get("CVE_ADDR_ID").toString())
                        : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);
                buyerDataAdressesBean.setNumState(map.get("NUM_STATE") != null && !map.get("NUM_STATE").equals("")
                        ? Integer.parseInt(map.get("NUM_STATE").toString())
                        : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);

                adresses.add(buyerDataAdressesBean);

            }

            Adresses userAdresses = new Adresses();
            Map<String, Object> addId = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(0);
            userAdresses.setId(addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID") != null && !addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID").equals("")
                    ? Integer.parseInt(addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID").toString())
                    : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);
            userAdresses.setAdresses(adresses);
            buyerDataServiceBean.setAddressList(userAdresses);
            BuyerDataServiceBean user = (BuyerDataServiceBean) entry.setValue(buyerDataServiceBean);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
    BuyerDataServiceBean buyerDataServiceBean;
    ArrayList<BuyerDataAdressesBean> addresses;
    Map<Integer, Object> row = (Map<Integer, Object>) mapResults.get("out_cur_buyer_data");

    BuyerDataServiceBean user = new BuyerDataServiceBean();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : row.entrySet()) {
        buyerDataServiceBean = new BuyerDataServiceBean();
        addresses = new ArrayList<>();

        buyerDataServiceBean.setBuyerId(entry.getKey());
        for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(i);

            BuyerDataAdressesBean buyerDataAdressesBean = new BuyerDataAdressesBean();
            if (i == 0) {
                Map<String, Object> userObj = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(0);
                buyerDataServiceBean.setLastName(
                        userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME") != null && !userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME").equals("")
                                ? userObj.get("NOM_LAST_NAME").toString()
                                : "");
                // Rest of the code...

            }

            // Rest of the code...

            addresses.add(buyerDataAdressesBean);
        }

        Adresses userAdresses = new Adresses();
        Map<String, Object> addId = (Map<String, Object>) row.get(0);
        userAdresses.setId(addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID") != null && !addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID").equals("")
                ? Integer.parseInt(addId.get("NUM_ADDRESS_LIST_ID").toString())
                : ConstantesUtil.RESP_INT_CERO);
        userAdresses.setAdresses(addresses);
        buyerDataServiceBean.setAddressList(userAdresses);

        entry.setValue(buyerDataServiceBean);
    }

    return buyerDataServiceBean;
}
```